# ML.NET advanced data option

Tags: ml.net

I am using ML.NET wizard and it picks some data for categorization. My question is what fields I need to check to be categorical, what fields to pick for features?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think you are asking the difference between categorical and numerical features, and the wizard is asking you to tell it which is categorical?

In machine learning, categorical features is data that has a finite amount of possible values, e.g for payment type you might only have two: "CREDIT" and "DEBIT"

More detail:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/prepare-data-ml-net#work-with-categorical-data